# IndexOf nao funciona em Arrays?

Tags: java, indexof

Tenho o seguinte código que detem um array com 7 valores,cada um para cada dia da semana. de seguida tenho de cria uma função que faz a soma desses 7 valores(concluido com sucesso),diz qual é o maior valor desse Array (concluido com sucesso) e depois indicar qual o dia em que tal valor ocorreu(é onde está o prolema).Continuo a ter um problema no int day=rainHours.indexOf(maxTempDay); em que me diz "cannot find symbol - method indexOf(int). Deixo aqui o código agradecia ajuda.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] rainHours=new int[]{1,3,0,0,6,3,8};
    int sum = rainInBusyDays(rainHours);
    System.out.println(sum);
    int maxValue=maxRain(rainHours);
    int maxTempDay=mostRainy(rainHours);
    int day=rainHours.indexOf(maxTempDay);
    System . out . println("O valor máximo é:" + maxValue + " no " + day + "º dia da semana ");

}

public static int rainInBusyDays(int[] rainH)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i =1; i<rainH.length-1 ;i++)
    {
        total =total + rainH[i];
    }
    return total;
}

public static int maxRain(int[] rainHo)
{
    int max = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<rainHo.length;j++)
    {
        if (rainHo[j] > max)
        {
            max= rainHo[j];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public static int mostRainy(int[] rainHou)
{
    int maxTempDay = 0;
    for(int k = 0 ; k<rainHou.length;k++)
    {
        if(rainHou[k] > maxTempDay)
        {
            maxTempDay = rainHou[k];             
        }
    }
    return maxTempDay;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe o método `indexOf` para arrays. Se você quiser saber o índice do int no array você pode:

1 - Fazer um `for` no array procurando o elemento (Essa função retorna o dia que teve a temperatura máxima, se ela não encontrar essa temperatura ela retorna `-1`)

```
public int maxTempDay(int maxTemp, int[] days) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i< days.length; i++) {
        if(maxTemp == days[i]) {
            //retorna o dia em que a temperatura estava máxima. 
            //Como o índice do array começa do zero você pode retornar i+1 para ter o dia;
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    // se terminar o for, não foi encontrado um dia com essa temperatura.
    return -1;
}
```

2 - Usar a classe `java.util.Arrays` para utilizar o método `indexOf` de um `List`

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(rainHours).indexOf(maxTempDay);
```

Comment: Então e como chamo esse "i" para que possa dar return no dia correto para imprimir na função principal?

Comment: @Phil eu editei minha resposta te explicando como usar o `i`